# VBA Variable from msgbox to report

Tags: vba, variables, report, msgbox

I have a macro which runs several Sql queries. One of these queries is run based off a date which in input in a msgbox within the macro (only companies after the date entered are generated).

Is it possible to put the value entered in the msgbox at the time the macro is run in a table by itself? (my ultimate goal is to put the value on a report to indicate that values displayed are after the following date: variable)

Below is my code:

```
Sub insertmsgboxvar()
Dim msgboxdate As Date
msgboxdate = InputBox("Enter a date. Accounts created AFTER the date will be returned.")
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT " & msgboxdate & " Into tblreqaccts ;"
End Sub
```

For some reason, when i run it, it creates the table (which did not previously exist) creates a column called Expr1000 and puts in a numerical value 5.96421471172962E-03. I already tried changing it to date format and I get a date from 1899.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sure you can. Below takes an input box and assigns it to a variable. This is then saved down in Range("A1") of Sheet1:

```
Dim formDate As Date

formDate = Application.InputBox("Input Date", "Date")

Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = formDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic SQL query that you might be running from your VBA:

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE DateField > yourmsgboxvalue
```

You can also do this:

```
SELECT yourmsgboxvalue as C23, C1,C2,C3 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE DateField > yourmsgboxvalue
```

So now you have the value entered in your messagebox within your actual resultset. Then you just need to work out how to display it once in your header. This is trivial for all out of the box reporting tools and should be easy enough if you have custom developed one.

We'll need more explanation of your code to help any futher.